# Matplotlib y-tick labels not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

For some reason the y-tick and y-tick labels aren't showing up on my plot. The variable `data` is a pandas dataframe: `rfr_scatter = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test, 'Model Predicted':rfr_predictions})`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def ScatterPlotter(notebooktab, data, test, pred):
    f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
    ax1 = f.add_subplot(111, title="Model Performance")

    for item in ([ax1.title, ax1.xaxis.label, ax1.yaxis.label] +
                 ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels()):
        item.set_fontsize(8)
        item.set_color('black')

    markersize = 0.8
    alpha = 0.05

    line = np.arange(min(test), min(test) + 35, 5)
    data.plot.scatter(x='Actual', y='Model Predicted', ax=ax1, s=markersize, alpha=alpha)
    ax1.set_xlim((min(test),max(test)))
    ax1.set_ylim((pred.min(),pred.max()))
    ax1.plot(line,line,clr_red,'--', label = "Perfect")

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, notebooktab)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

And i get this:
[image]

I have tried setting the yticks to visible, with no luck. I'm probably missing something simple...

EDIT: removing `ax1.set_ylim((pred.min(),pred.max()))` gives me a couple marks on the graph, it almost looks like the label is over the text, or the text isn't finishing rendering.

[image]

Comment: Curious. What does `ax1.get_yticks() ` return?

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: @Galen Printing to the shell I get `[0]`. If I do the same for `ax1.get_xticks()` I get `[ 20.  25.  30.  35.  40.  45.  50.  55.]`.

Comment: Do you get anything if you remove `ax1.set_ylim((pred.min(),pred.max()))`?

Comment: You should include your imports and some dummy data for a MCVE. At the moment I have no issues with your code (i.e., I get a y-axis) if I dummy out some of the parts you haven't included.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone Updated with imports.

Comment: @Galen I added a picture of what happens when that is removed.

Comment: what do you pass for notebooktab?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone `ScatterPlotter(self.TNotebook1_tabMP, rfr_scatter, y_test, rfr_predictions)` is my call. The notebook tab is `self.TNotebook1_tabMP = ttk.Frame(self.TNotebook1)` with the frame `self.TNotebook1 = ttk.Notebook(top)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `ax1.plot(line,line,clr_red,'--', label = "Perfect")` to `ax1.plot(line,line,'r--', label = "Perfect")` fixed the problem